# How can I get a list of file that match a list of regular expressions?

Tags: command-line, regex, find

I want to see what is not being backed up using regular expressions. The list is here: https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/What_Is_Not_Backing_Up#Admin_Excludes

I tried

```
$ cat | xargs -L 1 echo find /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe -regex -name
```

And pasted the list of regular expressions, which looked fine. When I removed the `echo`, it gave the error

```
find: paths must precede expression: .*/(?:42|d{8,}).*/(?:cp|~).*
```

I tried one line manually, and got

```
$ find /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe -regex -name .*.part
find: paths must precede expression: .*.part
```

I also tried using quotes

```
$ find /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe -regex -name '.*.part'
find: paths must precede expression: .*.part
```

I also tried changing the order

```
$ find -regex -name '.*.part' /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe
find: paths must precede expression: .*.part
```

So how do I find all the files that match all those regular expressions? I know some commands allow you to specify `@file` as an argument to get the command line option from a file, but I didn't see that in the `find` man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked

```
$ cat | xargs -L 1 -d \\n find 2>/dev/null /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe -regex
```

- `-L 1` means to only process 1 argument at a time for each `find` command and don't clump the arguments together into one giant command line
- `-d \\n` means use newline as an argument separator because some of the input arguments have spaces. You have to use double backslash so it isn't interpreted by the shell immediately.
- `2>/dev/null` prevents errors like 'unable to read directory ...`
- `-regex` means use regular expression for the file name. Apparently `-regex` and `-name` are mutually exclusive, even though I've used regular expressions with `-name` before.

Just paste the list of regular expressions and finish with enter and `^D`.